# Most Compatible Software for MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2014)

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina

I managed to upgrade to Sierra 10.12.6. Whats the next step for me? MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2014) Processor: 1.4 GHz Intel Core i5 Memory: 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5000 1536 MB

I want to have the latest yet most compatible software! Catalina from Appstore is still not installing '...target volume failed' Should I download a previous software (High Sierra or Mojave) the same way I downloaded Sierra? If yes then which one is the best one for my MacBook and its health...? also do you have a download link for your recommendation?

Comment: I would recommend macOS High Sierra (aka 10.13) first: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208969

You could then make a bootable clone of your system and further upgrade to a later macOS, or given sufficient free space, partition your drive and install a later macOS to test it for compatibility and features.

Answer (score 1):

MacBook Air Early 2014 allows to update to macOS Catalina (10.15), even the yet unreleased macOS BigSur (11.0) will run on it.

I suggest to use [macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) installer with
<kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> during a restart to upgrade to the latest macOS that is compatible with your Mac.